# Autocomplete Angularjs from $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-resource

I have a problem with an autocomplete and angularjs. I have several ajax request every time i type and this is unusable. I tried to use a timeout without success.. this is code:

```
$scope.autoCompleteResults = function(){
        $scope.aborter = $q.defer();

        $scope.resource = $resource(URL, {}, {
            getAutocompleteResults: {
                method: "GET",
                timeout: $scope.aborter.promise
            }
        });

        $scope.resource.getAutocompleteResults({}, function (data) {
            if ($scope.searchTxt.length > 1) {

                $scope.autocompleteViewResults = data.data;
                $scope.aborter.resolve();

            } else {
                $scope.autocompleteViewResults = [];
                $scope.search.aborter.reject();
            }
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `ng-model-options` attribute in order to limit the api callings.

Just append `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }"` to your input, the model will be updated only 0.5 sec after the last change. If the the trigger is a `ng-change` directive it will limit the amount of query.
Don't hestitate to use as well the input directives like `ng-minlength`and `ng-maxlength`

Moreover, you can use a boolean to block the api callings when a query is already in progress.

You could do something like this.

```
var Resource = $resource(URL, {},{ getAutocompleteResults: { method: "GET" }});

var locked = false;
function getMoreData() {

    if(locked)
        return;
    locked = true;

    Resource.autoCompleteResults()
        .$promise.then(function(data) {
            $scope.autocompleteViewResults = data;
            locked = false;
        });

}
```

Furthermore I highly recommend you to store your code logic into factories and/or services.

Comment: have i to declare a timeout in my resource however?

Comment: So, i can use the timeout as i have already done before, add your boolean code and even add the model-option?

Comment: yes sure, however, in this case you should use the boolean to know when abort the promise instead of simply block the function calling.

Comment: well seems working. Amazing!! thank you! Have you other suggestion to make all faster? I'm new in angularjs. You suggested to use ng-minlength, but as you can see i need "count" lenght of text in the input text to fill or empty my data. by the way,  this is the input i'm using: 

<input ng-model="searchTxt" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }" ng-change="autoCompleteResults()" type="text" placeholder="Search..">